# Getting all subviews of a subview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uibutton

Well, my problem is that as you can see in the image i have a subview and in that subview i have other views and inside that i have a uilabel and some uibuttons.

[image: viewcontroller layout]

My question is how to acess all that uibuttons and uilabel on each subview in the viewDidLoad so i can change some aspects of them when the app begins.

In my test i tried to change the color of the buttons.

I tried using this code but it didn't work:

```
for (UIView *view1 in self.view.subviews) {
    NSLog(@"%@----", view1);

    for(UIView *view2 in view1.subviews){

       NSLog(@"%@", view2);

       if ([view2 isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
          [(UIButton *)view2 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    }
  }
}
```

The nslog gives this:
[image: nslog image]

Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Try throwing some NSLogs in there to make sure that view1 and view2 are the views you expect them to be. Although if you are putting laying the views out in the Interface Builder and just need to set their colors when the app loads, couldn't you set their colors using the interface builder?

Comment: Yes i could use the interface builder but i also might need to add a border to them so simulate a grid and if i'm not mistaken the interface builder doesn't have the option of adding border to uibutton. 

i'll add the nslog on the question

Comment: Personally, I would create subclasses of UIView and create properties for each subview you want to change. IMO, that's much cleaner & more readable than iterating through multiple arrays of subviews.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either create `IBOutlets`, or use unique tags in all the objects you wish to reference and use `viewWithTag` to get a reference to the objects pointer.

If you use `viewWithTag`, make sure to check the object pointer against nil, to avoid runtime crashes.

To use `viewWithTag`, you need to assign a unique Tag in IB, see screenshot:

[image]

As you see my `UILabel` has here a Tag of 253 and to access it's pointer object I have to use `viewWithTag`:

```
UILabel *myTagLabel = (UILabel*)[self.view viewWithTag:253];
```

And as I suggested before using that pointer, check against `nil`:

```
if (myTagLabel) {
     //object pointer retrieved successfully
     myTagLabel.text = @"Hello";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, i thought on using the IBOutlets but since it still has a good number of buttons i didn't want to create a outlet for each one. 
So i went using

`@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutletCollection(UIButton) NSArray *conj_btn;`

and then 
`for (UIButton *botao in self.conj_btn) {
        [botao setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    }`

and that did the trick.

I´ll wait to see if @carlodurso can help me with my doubt before i give you the answer checkmark. 
Also i tried using viewWithTag but i only now how to use it on cells. how can i change all buttons with tags?

Comment: Thanks a lot, i'll try that and also starting to check against nil on my code.

Answer (score 2):

The way I'd go about this is:

```
    for (int i=0; i<[self.view.subviews count]; i++) {

        if ([[self.view.subviews objectAtIndex:i] isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
            UIButton *button = (UIButton *)[self.view.subviews objectAtIndex:i];
            [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
        }
    }
```

For more control over each subview I'd follow @Lefteris' suggestion.

Comment: i thought that would work but the weird thing its i add a nslog to show me the self.view.subviews and it only shows me:
    "<_UILayoutGuide: .....,
    "<_UILayoutGuide: ......,

it doesn't show the views and it never enters the if clause. 
Don't know what i'm doing wrong.

Comment: I see. If you'd attach a sample project we may be able to help you further.

Comment: No need, i saw that your code works well and does what it suposse to do. 
I'm seeing that having a lot of views inside a view is getting me problems but for now i fixed my problem using the IBOutletCollection. 

Thanks for the help and the code. It might come very handy on the future.

Answer (score 2):

I think this start happening since Xcode 6, it's not because you have too many nested views.

If you check in `- (void)viewDidLoad` or `-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated`, you won't be able to get to a subview, even with `viewWithTag:`.

You should do your checks in:

`- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews`

or

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
```

Your subviews will be recognized inside these methods.

Comment: Nice one. Didn't knew about that. I guess for now on if i'll keep in mind your answer when the same problem emerges again.

Answer (score 0):

```
Can you please try this.

int screensize;
UIScrollView *scroll;
-(void)setUpView{
    screensize = self.view.frame.size.width;
    scroll = [[UIScrollView alloc]init];
    scroll.frame = CGRectMake(0, 64, screensize, SCROLLHEIGHT);
    scroll.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
    scroll.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;

    int x = 5;

    for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {

        UIView *bgview = [[UIView alloc]init];
        bgview.frame = CGRectMake(x, 5, VIEWWIDTH, VIEWHEIGHT);
        bgview.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

        UIImageView *carimage = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
        carimage.frame = CGRectMake(0, 5, VIEWWIDTH, IMAGEHEIGHT);
        [carimage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"User"]];
        carimage.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        carimage.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

        UILabel *underlinelbl = [[UILabel alloc]init];
        underlinelbl.frame = CGRectMake(0, carimage.frame.origin.y+carimage.frame.size.height+2, VIEWWIDTH, UNDERLINELABELHEIGHT);
        underlinelbl.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];

        UILabel *textlbl = [[UILabel alloc]init];
        textlbl.frame = CGRectMake(0, underlinelbl.frame.origin.y+underlinelbl.frame.size.height, VIEWWIDTH, TEXTLABELHEIGHT);
        textlbl.font = [UIFont regularFont10];
        textlbl.text = @"name";
        textlbl.textColor = [UIColor customBlackColor];
        textlbl.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;

        UILabel *numberlbl = [[UILabel alloc]init];
        numberlbl.frame = CGRectMake(0,textlbl.frame.origin.y+textlbl.frame.size.height ,VIEWWIDTH , TEXTLABELHEIGHT);
        numberlbl.text = @"000";
        numberlbl.font = [UIFont regularFont10];
        numberlbl.textColor = [UIColor customBlackColor];
        numberlbl.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;

        UIButton *carname = [[UIButton alloc]init];
        carname.frame = CGRectMake(bgview.frame.origin.x, bgview.frame.origin.y, VIEWWIDTH, VIEWHEIGHT);
        carname.tag = i+1;
        [carname addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonclick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [carname setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];


        [scroll addSubview:bgview];
        [bgview addSubview:carimage];
        [bgview addSubview:underlinelbl];
        [bgview addSubview:textlbl];
        [bgview addSubview:numberlbl];
        [scroll addSubview:carname];

        x += bgview.frame.size.width+5;
    }
    scroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake( x, SCROLLHEIGHT);
    scroll.backgroundColor = [UIColor customLightGrayColor];
    [self.view addSubview:scroll];
}

-(void)buttonclick:(id)sender{

    UIButton *selectedButton = (UIButton *)sender;

    for (UIView *subView in scroll.subviews) {
        if ([subView isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
            UIButton *btn = (UIButton*)subView;
            if (btn.tag == selectedButton.tag) {
                btn.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
                btn.layer.borderColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor].CGColor;
            }else{
                btn.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
                btn.layer.borderColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
            }
        }
    }

}
```